# ExecuteSqlCommand - Update byte - Error

Tags: c#, sql

Segue código:

```
var bytes = ConvertTo.Bytes(file);

int num = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    $"UPDATE dbo.Table" +
    $"SET Video = '{bytes}' " +
    $"WHERE id = {Id} ");
```

Segue código para converter:

```
public static byte[] Bytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var length = file.InputStream.Length;
    byte[] fileData = null;
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
    {
        fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
    }
    return fileData;
}
```

Recebo erro:

> A conversão implícita do tipo de dados varchar em varbinary(max) não é
>   permitida. Use a função CONVERT para executar essa consulta.

Alguma solução?

Comment: Qual o tipo da coluna `Video` no banco?

Comment: @LINQ, varbinary(max)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deveria usar *queries* parametrizadas para fazer este trabalho.

De qualquer forma, você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
var valor = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(arraytoinsert).Replace("-", "");

int num = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
          $"UPDATE dbo.Table" +
          $"SET Video = {valor} " +
          $"WHERE id = {Id} ");
```

---

Usando uma query parametrizada, ficaria assim:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Table SET Video = (@pVideo)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pVideo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000).Value = bytes;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: LINQ, se eu quiser forçar variável como nulo, como eu faço ? Eu recebo esse erro: `A consulta parametrizada '(@imagem1 varbinary(max) ,@imagem2 nvarchar(4000),@imagem3 nvarc' espera o parâmetro '@imagem2', que não foi fornecido.` , quando defino só a imagem1 diferente de `null` e o resto como `null`.

Comment: Fiz nova pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255098/erro-ao-fazer-update-quando-defino-vari%C3%A1vel-como-null