# Erro ao fazer UPDATE quando defino variável varbinary como `null`

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-update

Segue código:

```
var file = Request.Files;
var list = new List<byte[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (file.Count > i)
    {
        list.Add(ConvertTo.Bytes(file[i]));
        continue;
    }
    list.Add(null);
}

int count = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    $"UPDATE dbo.Table " +
    $"SET Imagem1 = @imagem1, Imagem2 = @imagem2, Imagem3 = @imagem3, Imagem4 = @imagem4 " +
    $"WHERE id = {Id}",
    new SqlParameter("imagem1", list[0] ?? null),
    new SqlParameter("imagem2", list[1] ?? null),
    new SqlParameter("imagem3", list[2] ?? null),
    new SqlParameter("imagem4", list[3] ?? null));
```

Erro:

> A consulta parametrizada '(@imagem1 varbinary(max) ,@imagem2
>   nvarchar(4000),@imagem3 nvarc' espera o parâmetro '@imagem2', que não
>   foi fornecido.

Esse erro acontece quando usuário escolher só uma imagem.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: debugando qual o conteudo do list[1] ?

Comment: se voce escolhe 2 imagens dá erro na 3?

Comment: @imagem1 varbinary(max) ,@imagem2 nvarchar(4000),@imagem3 nvarc ?????? todos os parametros sao varbinary? nao entendi agora.. o primeiro parece ser diferente dos demais..

Comment: sim.. mas to estranhando ele falar q os tipos sao diferentes... no seu banco de dados como está ?

Comment: cara tenta colocar isso: nos seus parameters
new SqlParameter("imagem1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = list[0];

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68665/discussion-between-thiago-loureiro-and-matheus-miranda).

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Você precisa usar `SqlBinary.Null`

Comment: Isso mesmo @LINQ, o problema foi resolvido, obrigado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matheus você precisa trocar o **null** pelo **SqlBinary.Null**, muita gente teve esse problema com valores nulos e varbinary no banco!

```
int count = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    $"UPDATE dbo.Table " +
    $"SET Imagem1 = @imagem1, Imagem2 = @imagem2, Imagem3 = @imagem3, Imagem4 = @imagem4 " +
    $"WHERE id = {Id}",
    new SqlParameter("imagem1", list[0] ?? SqlBinary.Null),
    new SqlParameter("imagem2", list[1] ?? SqlBinary.Null),
    new SqlParameter("imagem3", list[2] ?? SqlBinary.Null),
    new SqlParameter("imagem4", list[3] ?? SqlBinary.Null));
```